# PHPStorm not indexing include paths set in project

Tags: phpstorm

After I give an include path to my new project, PHPStorm doesn't index that directory.

I added the PHPUnit directory, but have no autocompletion for its classes.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot showing the relevant configuration in PhpStorm? Did you try File | Invalidate Caches?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Note: this solution will delete the cache, **including local history**, *for all projects*.  The indexes will be rebuilt next time you open a project but the local history is gone forever. With that said...

Try selecting <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Invalidate Caches / Restart...</kbd> from the menu then <kbd>Invalidate and Restart</kbd>.