# PhpStorm how to refresh folder content or whole project tree

Tags: php, phpstorm

This may be a dumb question, but I can not find an option to refresh folder content in project tree (PhpStorm IDE).
Is this (really basic) feature missing?

I know, that content is refreshed automatically, but in some types of folders, where files are generated and changed often this does not work.

Comment: `File | Synchronize` (3rd button on main toolbar) does exactly this.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

right click on the folder and then synchronize 'nameOfFolder' to refresh a specific folder

Comment: How do you do this automatically? If I create a file from the command line tool, then I need to do this every time, which is not desirable.

Comment: I'm looking for this exact functionality to aid in my Gulp workflow. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Looking for solution to integrate into Gulp workflow also

Comment: F5 should do this :(

Comment: @DIEGOF.G.no F5 is bind to copy/move in phpstorm but Ctrl + Alt + Y synchronize all folders

Comment: This happens automatically for all my other projects. Why is this one project not auto updating? There has to be a setting controlling this.

Answer (score 29):

If that does not solve your problem it might be that you have an invalid cache. You can solve this issue by invalidating your cache.

Select <kbd>File</kbd> then <kbd>Invalidate Caches / Restart...</kbd> from the menu then <kbd>Invalidate and Restart</kbd>.

---

**Note:** *this solution will delete the cache, including local history, for all projects.*

This is also explained in [the answer to this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14727417/1697459)

Comment: This is a valuable solution - I had a folder that was being displayed >30 times in the Project files. Even after removing the folder from the filesystem altogether and pressing the Synchronize button, the issue persisted. I deleted the project and .idea files, then re-created a new project and even the Project Root browser was still showing the duplicated directory (which was no longer even present in the filesystem). Invalidating the Cache and restarting the IDE solved the problem!

Comment: You deserve a beer, been using `Synchronize` and it fails always. Then I have to uninstall and reinstall PhpStorm to just get it to full re-index the project.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Image for answer]

As per above screenshot click <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

#### Tested in phpstorm 2016.3

The behavior I've want is for the IDE to be up-to-date with any file changes made via the terminal or external application (like Git).

I found this solution via Google:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206356869-PhpStorm-should-scan-project-directory-for-changes

Select <kbd>File</kbd> then <kbd>Settings</kbd> then <kbd>Appearance & Behavior</kbd> then select <kbd>System Settings</kbd> and finally under **Synchronization** checkmark <kbd>Synchronize files on frame or editor tab activation</kbd>

If the above directions are long winded, Goto settings and search for "synchronization".

[image]

Comment: I'm on the 2021 version of phpStorm and it no longer seems to have this option

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the root folder that is showing in your project tree. Then click on "Reload from Disk".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30719488)